# How may I evaluate my self study of Machine Learning?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, self-study

I am trying to learn Machine Learning on my own. To do this, I try to read from textbooks, good web-based materials like Stanford or Caltech. I try to work out my exercises, and try to discuss my understanding with seniors and peers. Things are more or less going fine, but sometimes I feel the need to cross check some of the concepts I learned. I write can write a synopsis, but sending a synopsis to a room / forum like this feels slightly awkward.

Can anybody suggest how may I do that?

Comment: Participate in competitions like the ones on Kaggle or Codalab.

Comment: +1. @MarcClaesen This is a good answer on it's own right. :)

Answer (score 2):

Download an app for your cell phone to collect some sensor data, such as acceleration from gyroscopes. Write machine learning program to learn something about yourself. For instance, try to detects when you're sitting vs. standing. After training the model on past data, test it on new data and see if it learned anything.

Comment: +1. I like it: you learned something about ML if you can write a program that learns something about you.

Comment: (You said +1 but you didn't upvote :P) I don't think this is a good idea because the user does not have benchmark. He cannot compare/test himself against others and he cannot know if his solution is wrong, trivial or simply excellent.

Comment: The purpose of the project is to teach his phone to detect whether *he* is sitting or standing. It's not about learning about other people' That could be a larger project in future.

Comment: When I said "against others" I meant other solutions. If he gets it right 90% and pretty much all other people get it right 99% his understanding is wrong. If other people get it right 85% of the time his implementation is excellent. Without a benchmark though there is not concept of "evaluating the solution". @amoeba: No probs; I just saw it and I was like "Hm.... Something is missing here."

Comment: @usεr11852, Machine Learning is a very general term, like OLS. If I say use OLS, it doesn't mean there's just one way to do it. You can create a multitude of ML algorithms, very different ones, and compare them against each other.

Comment: I am slightly revising the question as a new post.

Comment: @RichardParker, you have to resolve this post then

Comment: How may I do that? Please suggest.

Comment: @RichardParker, pick the best answer.

Comment: You gave the only answer. And others are comments. It may work but I do not use App based feature phone.